# Help in determining whether I have a male or female kitten

Tags: cats, gender-differentiation

Is my kitten a male or female?

[image: Is my kitten a male or female?[1]]

Answer (score 1):

I think your cat is male

A female kitten's genitals will resemble an upside-down exclamation point, with the vertical vaginal slit sitting just below the anus and with very little spacing in between (when the cat is upside down and facing you). A male kitten's organ looks more like a colon, with the penis residing just below the anus and separated by enough space to accommodate his testicles